# Make repo. public but disable cloning in Bitbucket?

Tags: git, bitbucket

Currently I would like to showcase my projects on my resume however the projects are on Bitbucket. I understand you could freely showcase your projects on GitHub but I chose Bitbucket so that they cannot be cloned. My question is if there are certain settings in Bitbucket that would allow people to browse certain repositories but not clone them? I know if I make my repository public anyone can browse the code. Is there a way for me to make my repository public and disable cloning for anonymous/guest users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go to the repo settings in Bitbucket

```
Settings > Repository details > Access Level > disable "This is a private repository"

Settings > Repository details > Landing page > select "Overview"
```

That way the repo source is open to public but only with `read` access

Comment: @JamesFranco sure as you make it public

Comment: When I try to view the repository in anonymous mode Bitbucket wants me to sign in.

Comment: shouldn't be the case, once you  make the repo public, get the URL of the repo and try to access it from a different browser (ie another one which does not store your bitbucket account already) - should then be visible for browsing

Comment: Ok so right now my repo is private. If I make it public then wont anonymous users be able to clone the repository as well. I only want me to be able to clone it while anonymous users to only browse the repo

Comment: have you tested the "Overview" option as suggested?

Comment: Make the repo public and set it to overview ?